# I want to delete node from singly linked list using only one local pointer variable, what error in this code section?

Tags: c

I want to delete node from singly linked list using only one local pointer variable in C, the debugger stops on the `free(cur)` of the `delete` function without any error, but it runs normally in `free(cur->next)`, why is this? What error in this code section?

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct
{
    struct node *header;
} List;

void add(List *pList, int val)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof pList->header);
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = pList->header;
    pList->header = new_node;
}

void delete(List *pList, int val)
{
    struct node *cur = pList->header;
    if (cur != NULL)
    {
        if (cur->val == val)
        {
            struct node *temp = cur->next;
            //debug stop in free(cur) without any error,why?
            free(cur);
            cur = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            while (cur->next != NULL && cur->next->val != val)
            {
                cur = cur->next;
            }

            if (cur->next != NULL)
            {
                struct node *temp = cur->next->next;
                // run normally, why?
                free(cur->next);
                cur->next = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `malloc`?

Comment: "debug stop in free(cur) without any error,why?" - Did you set a breakpoint?

Comment: of course, I set a brekpoint in free(cur),but I can't run continuously, in vscode

Comment: Please create a [mre]. I suggest to add a `main` function that calls your functions `add` and `delete` with hard-coded data in a way that reproduces the problem.

Comment: By the least, `malloc(sizeof pList->header)` is wrong. You should use `sizeof(node)`, not `sizeof(node*)`.

Comment: Your allocation requests only space for a pointer, not a node.

Comment: OT: `header` should be named `head`.

Comment: Wow!!! you exit from a program without a simple error message?  You are brave!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in the `add` function: you pass the size of a pointer to `malloc` instead of the size of the `node` structure. A safer way to always pass the correct size is this:

```
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```

As coded, the memory allocated is too small and you have undefined behavior when you initialize the structure, writing beyond the end of the allocated block.

There is another problem in the `delete()` function: you do not update `pList->header` when you free the first node.

Here is a modified block:

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct {
    struct node *header;
} List;

void add(List *pList, int val) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = pList->header;
    pList->header = new_node;
}

void delete(List *pList, int val) {
    struct node *cur = pList->header;
    if (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->val == val) {
            pList->header = cur->next;
            free(cur);
        } else {
            while (cur->next != NULL) {
                struct node *temp = cur->next;
                if (temp->val == val) {
                    cur->next = temp->next;
                    free(temp);
                    break;
                }
                cur = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, malloc(sizeof(*new_node)) is correct. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)